# Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands

Tags: operator-keyword, swift4

Good evening lovely community,
this is my first post, please have mercy, if I do something wrong. 
I know there are some similar questions here, but I doesn't understand it.
Maybe I understand, if someone explain it on my code.

// these are my two TextFields and the "finish"-Button.

```
@IBOutlet weak var goalPlayerOne: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var goalPlayerTwo: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var finishedGameButton: UIButton!
```

// here are my function, it should tell me, which Player has won like A < B, so B has won.

```
 @IBAction func finishedGameButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    // define UITextField as Integer

let goalPlayerOne = "";
let goalOne = Int(goalPlayerOne);

let goalPlayerTwo = "";
let goalTwo = Int(goalPlayerTwo);
```

// here is the problem: 
"Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands"
// if I make a '==' it works

```
if goalOne < goalTwo{    
    displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "Player Two wins")
    return
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you look at the declaration for `Int`'s initializer that takes a `String`, you can see by the `?` after `init` that it returns an optional:

```
convenience init?(_ description: String)
```

This means you have to unwrap it before you can do most things with it (`==` is an exception, since the `Optional` type has an overload for that operator).

There are four main ways to unwrap your optionals:

## 1: If let

```
if let goalOne = Int(someString) {
    // do something with goalOne
}
```

## 2: Guard let

```
guard let goalOne = Int(someString) else {
    // either return or throw an error
}

// do something with goalOne
```

## 3: `map` and/or `flatMap`

```
let someValue = Int(someString).map { goalOne in
    // do something with goalOne and return a value
}
```

## 4: Provide a default value

```
let goalOne = Int(someString) ?? 0 // Or whatever the default value should be
```

If you unwrap all your optionals, you'll be able to compare them as you expect.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help.
I can`t vote, because my rep is not enough. Sorry :-(

Answer (score 1):

This error can also occur if you are comparing a custom type (ie: struct or class) for which you haven't implemented the [Comparable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable) protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Well, by using guard statement you can check if both values are not nil, and converting it to Int typ

```
    guard let value_one = Int(goalPlayerOne), let value_two = Int(goalPlayerTwo) else {
        print("Some value is nil")
        return
    }
```

so you can safely compare two values.

```
    if value_one < value_two {
       //Do something
    }
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.