# Adding the values of two [String : Int] dictionaries in Swift

Tags: swift

So i am trying to add the values of two `[String : Int]` dictionaries in Xcode using the latest Swift. My code is shown below. Both dictionaries have keys from `q1` to `q23` with values attached. This is why the random number stops at 23. The key `q1` has no use in this function (which is why the random number starts at 2). The  dictionary values are given by by another view controller during the segue to this viewController, I do not assign them manually. There is no need for the values in the dictionaries to be optionals as they **will** have been assigned values to get to this viewController.

I've been googling for an hour, but I cannot understand the reduce, combine or map functions as they would apply to this, and doing something so complex when I simply want to add seems like I'm overlooking an easier method.

```
var p1Pre:[String:Int]  = [“q1” : 1]

var p2Pre:[String:Int]  = [“q1” : 1]
var combPre:[String:Int]  = [“q1” : 0]

var pick = 0

// generates random number 2-23
func pickRandom(){
    pick = Int.random(in:2...23)
} 

func addPrefs(){
    // this is where i'm having trouble
    combPre[“q\(pick)] = p1Pre[“q\(pick)”] + p2Pre[“q\(pick)”]
    print(combPre[“q\(pick)”]
    // I get an error at the plus sign here
}
```

I'm trying to add the values at specific keys inside a two dictionaries (`p1Pre` and `p2Pre`) and the result will be stored in combPre.   I want to build a function so if `p1Pre[“q2”] == 1` and  `p2Pre[“q2”] == 2`, then `combPre[“q2”] = 3`.
I get an error at the plus sign that says `“binary operator “+” cannot be applied to two ‘Int?’ Operands"`. How would I make this work? Thank you

Comment: The issue is that's there is not guarnatee that `p1Pre[“q\(pick)”]` exists. So its value is an optional Int (explaining the part of your error message `Int?`).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252077/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-int-operands

Comment: You can use back ticks to write `inline highlighted  code`.

Comment: Can I force it to not be an optional? Because I know it will always exist when this code is ran. I believe its called force unwrapping? How do I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Just add a `!` next to the variable name. Note that if it doesn't exist for some reason, the app will crash.

Comment: Thank you SO much Tissoni!! That made my code run flawlessly doing what i wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you access a dictionary using the subscript, the type of the expression is always the optional of the value type, because the key that you are using might not exist in the dictionary. You cannot add two optional `Int`s together.

You need to consider the case of "what if the key `“q\(pick)”` does not exist in the dictionary?", and unwrap the two optionals accordingly.

In my opinion, the sensible thing to do here, when the key does not exist, is just to use the value `0`, since it is the identity of addition:

```
combPre[“q\(pick)] = (p1Pre[“q\(pick)”] ?? 0) + (p2Pre[“q\(pick)”] ?? 0)
```

If you are **100%** sure that the key will exist, you can consider force-unwrapping it:

```
combPre[“q\(pick)] = p1Pre[“q\(pick)”]! + p2Pre[“q\(pick)”]!
```

Only do this if you are **100%** sure, as in, "if the keys don't exist, then something really bad must have happened" kind of situation.

Comment: *"if the keys don't exist, then something really bad must have happened"* - you mean "if the keys don't exist, then something really bad *will happen*". :)

Comment: @rmaddy No, I meant to say that you should only force unwrap only if "the keys being there" is a precondition. So if you are in a situation where if the keys are not there means that your app cannot recover from whatever mistake caused them not to be there. You might as well crash with `!`.

Comment: Thank you! Very nice explanation! You answered my question, and taught me a whole new possible solution! Thank you! The user cannot get to this screen without assigning values to the keys q1 to q23. If they didnt click the buttons to assign values, the app would simply never segue here.