# how can I fix arithametic expression calulation to Int

Tags: ios, swift, casting

I am trying to calculate body fat related calculation but it will give me error binary operator can not be applied on operands.

it is gives me error like this

> error: :3:22: error: binary operator '/' cannot be applied to
>   operands of type 'Optional' and 'Int' print((lbs * Int(Fat /
>   100)))

Here is my expression.  how I can solve this.

```
let bodyFatPounds = (lbs * Int(Fat / 100))
let LBM = Double(lbs - bodyFatPounds)
```

Comment: How did you declare the value for *Fat*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252077/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-int-operands) Very similar

Comment: Int value for fat

Comment: I need the code of your declaration. Please give the line of code.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya it is expression execution not a copy...  it is not a copy should i get anser over there why it is not division operation perform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Fat` value in your code is optional and that's why it showing this error. Use to convert like this

```swift
let bodyFatPounds = (lbs * Int((Fat ?? 0) / 100))
let LBM = Double(lbs - bodyFatPounds)
```