# Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to two 'Double?' operands

Tags: swift

var result = (dimensione-base)/2

dimensione & base are two "Double?" number, how can i solve this?

i want to calculate this, but he always gives me this error:"Binary operator - cannot be applied to two "double?" operands.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252077/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-int-operands

Answer (score 1):

`Double?` is an optional type. That means a variable of this type can be `nil`. So before making an operation with them, you need to make sure these variables actually hold a value :

```swift
if let dimensione = dimensione,
   let base = base
{
    var result = (dimensione-base)/2
    // Use result here
}else{
    // Do something here when dimensione or base is nil.
}
```

You could also prefer to assign them a default value when they are nil (but in this case it seems less secure) :

```swift
var result = ((dimensione ?? 0)-(base ?? 0))/2
```

Here, if nil, 0 will be used instead.